# How do I write a dataset which contains only header (no rows) into a hdfs location (csv format) such that it contains the header when downloaded?

Tags: java, csv, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I have a dataset which contains only header (id,name,age) and 0 rows. 
I want to write it into an hdfs location as a csv file using

```
DataFrameWriter dataFrameWriter = dataset.write();
Map<String, String> csvOptions = new HashMap<>();
csvOptions.put("header", "true");
dataFrameWriter = dataFrameWriter.options(csvOptions);
dataFrameWriter.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).csv(location);
```

In the hdfs location , the files are:

```
1. _SUCCESS
2. tempFile.csv
```

If I go to that location and download the file (tempFile.csv) , I get an empty csv file.
Have tried with header true and false both.
How do I write the header as a content of the csv file?

Comment: Does your data set has 0 rows or 1 row that contains the header?

Comment: when I do dataset.collect() , it gives 0 rows. But the dataset has the schema details which is the header of the csv file from which this dataset was created.

Comment: Indeed, when writing an empty dataset to csv, it does not seem to write headers.

Answer (score 2):

Well this is a workaround. In Scala, you can do something like this:

```
df.take(1).isEmpty match {

    case true => sc.parallelize(Array(df.schema.map(_.name).mkString(",")))
                .saveAsTextFile("temp")
    case false => df.write.save("temp")

}
```

`df.schema` returns the schema of dataframe `df` as `StructType`.

`_.name` returns the name of each column in the schema.

`mkString(",")` converts the Resultant Sequence of names to a comma separated String

Something similar can be done for Java, I guess.

Comment: We have to get the column names , create a string and then save it. Do you think this is a bug from spark end ?

Comment: @Echo I wouldn't call it a bug because the dataframe you are trying to write is empty which wouldn't fit in as a requirement for general cases. Let's just say yours is a special case instead of calling it a bug.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the code, you will find that the header is only written when there is at least one row.

**UnivocityGenerator.scala**

```
  def write(row: InternalRow): Unit = {
    if (printHeader) {
      gen.writeHeaders()
    }
    gen.writeRow(convertRow(row): _*)
    printHeader = false
  }
```